# python argparse stops parsing after it encounters '$'

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am trying to parse a command line using argparse

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

argparser = ArgumentParser(prog="parse", description="desc")

create.add_argument("--name",dest="name",required=True,help="Name for element")
args = argparser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

When I execute this with below command

```
python argparser.py  --name "input$output$"
```

The output is:

```
('args:', Namespace(name='input$'))
```

Expected Output:

```
('args:', Namespace(name='input$output$'))
```

Can you please help figure out what am I doing wrong ?
Why argparse stops parsing after encountering a special char?

Comment: Try escaping the `$`, using `/$` instead

Comment: Look at `sys.argv` to see what `argparse` has to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because most shells consider strings starting with $ as a variable, and when quoted with double quotes, the shell tries to replace it with its value.

Jut open a terminal/console and type this in the shell (this works in both bash and fish):

```
echo "hi$test"  # prints hi trying to interpolate the variables 'test'
echo 'hi$test' # prints hi$test no interpolation for single quotes
```

This happens before the shell starts application processes. So 
I think when calling your application, you'd need to pass in the string quoted by single quotes, or escape the *$* with a backslash.

```
echo "hi\$test" # prints hi$test since $ is escaped
```

If you want to see what Python actually receives from the shell as an argument, directly inspect `sys.argv` (that's where `argparse` and other modules a like read the command line arguments).

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

In this specific case in the question, what happens is that your shell parses the `input$output$` and tries to interpolate the variable `$output`, but there no such variable defined, so it gets replaced by an empty string. So what is actually being passed to Python as the argument is `input$` (the last dollar sign stays in there because it's just a single dollar sign and can not be the name of a variable).

Comment: Is there any alternate way other then escaping it with '\'.

Comment: Depends on your shell. Bash is very common, so I assume you're using bash. For example I use fish and `echo "hi$test$"` doesn't run (fish complains about the last `$` which is a variable without a name), but bash ignores it and treats it as a literal dollar sign. But the most common way to prevent interpolation (that I know of) is either using single quotes, or escaping with backslash.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to your shell environment, since in `bash`, `$` signals the start of a variable. `$output` would probably be substituted for the empty string. `$` on its own won't be substituted.